# How do I update my PID on a timer?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I am trying to update my process's state on a 10 second timer.

```
-define(INTERVAL, 3000).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

action(Pid, Action) ->
  gen_server:call(Pid, Action).

init([]) -> 
  erlang:send_after(?INTERVAL, self(), trigger),
  {ok, temple:new()}.
```

what I want to do is call this

```
handle_call({fight}, _From, Temple) ->
  NewTemple = temple:fight(Temple),
  {reply, NewTemple, NewTemple};
```

So I try

```
handle_info(trigger, _State) ->
   land:action(self(), {fight}),
   erlang:send_after(?INTERVAL, self(), trigger);
```

but I get

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Dec-2016::19:00:35 ===
** Generic server <0.400.0> terminating
** Last message in was trigger
** When Server state == {{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                               {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                []},
                               {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []}}},
                         []}
** Reason for termination ==
** {function_clause,[{land,terminate,
                           [{timeout,{gen_server,call,[<0.400.0>,{fight}]}},
                            {{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                   {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                    [],[]},
                                   {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                     [],[],[]}}},
                             []}],
                           [{file,"src/land.erl"},{line,47}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that with `land:action(self(), {fight})`, you're attempting to make a `call` to the same gen_server in which you're currently handling the `trigger` message. Two important facts will explain why this can't work:

- A `call` always waits for the result to be returned.
- A gen_server is a process, and a process can handle only one message at a time.

In handling the `trigger` message, you're saying to `call` back to yourself and wait for yourself to process the `{fight}` message. Since you're in the middle of handling the `trigger` message, though, you'll never get to the `{fight}` message. You're effectively in a deadlock with yourself. That's why you're getting a timeout.

P.S. Posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is far more likely to get you good answers.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that there is no `terminate` clause in the land server module, you should have a warning when you compile the land server module.

The `terminate` clause is called because a timeout occurs during the gen_server call with the parameters `(Pid = <0.400.0>, Message = {fight})`, which was called on line `land:action(self(), {fight}),`. A call to a gen_server must be completed within a maximum time, by default 5000ms, You have to reduce the time spent in the fight action.

Note that it is not a good idea to increase the server timeout since a gen_server call is blocking: during the execution of a gen_server call no new message can be handled, and in your example , it is also blocking the execution of the `handle_info(trigger, _State)` code.

Last point, the clause `handle_info(trigger, _State)` should return a tuple of the form `{noreply,NewState}` while the last line `erlang:send_after(?INTERVAL, self(), trigger);` returns a timer reference, you have to modify this line.